# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. WPF closing all windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to close all Windows in WPF. The windows were all spawned in different threads.

here is my function :

```
`
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (window == Application.Current.MainWindow)
                window.Close();
        }
        //MessageBox.Show(varWindows.ToString());
        //for (int intCounter = App.Current.Windows.Count; intCounter > 0; intCounter--)
        //    App.Current.Windows[intCounter - 1].Hide();
    });

}`
```

Comment: which line you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you are accesing the UI objects from the right thread. Use the application's dispatcher instead of the current window's dispatcher:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    var a = Application.Current.Windows.Count;
    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (window == Application.Current.MainWindow)
        {
            var windowHandle = window;
            window.Dispatcher.Invoke(windowHandle.Close);
        }
    }
});
```

This will work if you want to close the main window, but windows from other threads won't be in the collection. I would strongly suggest you rather use the application's dispatcher to open all windows on the same application UI thread instead.