# WPF C# call window function from App

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, gps

i'm developping an app that use a GPS connected to the port com of my computer.

My application get 2 Windows, the first one is a display window, i will show all my GPS datas and the second one is a Map.

I have put all my code for opening the COM port and read it in the App.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using tmagpsapi;

namespace TDF
{
public partial class App : Application
{


    private tmagpsapi.NMEA gps;
    private tmaSerialport sp;


    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        gps = new NMEA();
        sp = new tmaSerialport();

        sp.ComPortOpen += new tmaSerialport.ComPortOpenEventHandler(comportOpen);
        sp.ComPortError += new tmaSerialport.ComPortErrorEventHandler(comportError);
        sp.ComPortClosed += new tmaSerialport.ComPortClosedEventHandler(comportClosed);
        gps.SuccessfulFix += new NMEA.SuccessfulFixEventHandler(gpsSuccessFix);

        sp.Openport(30, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, tmagpsapi.tmaSerialport.enumDatabits.Bit8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One, tmagpsapi.tmaSerialport.enumBaudRates.BaudRate9600);
        sp.LineRecieved += sp_LineRecieved;


    }

    void sp_LineRecieved(string Data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.MainWindow != null)
            {
                var currentWindow = this.MainWindow as GPSWindow;
                currentWindow.GPSHandle(Data);

            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("NULL");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

    }

        private void comportClosed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("COM PORT CLOSED");
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("COM PORT CLOSED");
    }

    private void comportError(System.Exception es, String message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error : " + message);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error : " + message);
    }

    private void comportOpen() {
        Console.WriteLine("COM PORT OPENED");
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("COM PORT OPENED");
    }
    private void gpsSuccessFix(tmagpsapi.NMEA_Position position)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("GPS OK");
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("GPS OK");

    }

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Close();
    }
}}
```

As you can see in this code, when i start the app, i open my COM Port and when i close the app i closed it.

When i have a new data on my COM Port the function sp_LineRecieved is called.
In this function i want to send those data to my currentWindow opened. To do that i have create an interface named "GPSWindow" (with one method void GPSHandle(string data))

But when I try to call the currentWindow.GPSHandle(Data) i got an error on my catch : "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

I have try to use the Application.Current.Dispatcher but every thing i tried send me this result.

Maybe i can pass those data with an event handler but i don't know how to do it.

**My Question is:**

How can I access a thread which is already used by a different thread ?

```
void GPSWindow.GPSHandle(string data)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("GPS : " + data);
    }
```

Comment: [Is this useful?](https://github.com/jathalls/SR420-2/blob/master/SR6/GPS.cs)

Comment: In what exactly step exception occurring? How do you manipulate UI elements inside `GPSHandle`? Can you provide exception stacktrace?

Comment: The exception append on the currentWindow.GPSHandle(Data), i put you the code of the function in the message

Comment: if you really wan't to do it in app.cs, try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24051789/352101)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

1 ) Add the folowing event handller in **App** class

```
 public static event EventHandler<String> RaiseWhenANewLineRecieved  = delegate {};
```

2 )  When a new line received add the following

```
RaiseWhenANewLineRecieved(this, Data);
```

3) Add the event listener in the  MainWindow's constructor

```
App.RaiseWhenANewLineRecieved += App_RaiseWhenANewLineRecieved;
```

4) Show the data in the MainWindow

```
 void App_RaiseWhenANewLineRecieved(object sender, string e)
 {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("GPS : " + e);
 }
```

Comment: Haha you are a genious <3